# user access frequency for individual files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I would like to get data access frequency count for individual file in Hadoop distributed file system. I have 5 hadoop nodes cluster and I would like to change replication factor based on file popularity. Can I get it from hadoop log files? As far as I learn from these log files, I did not find any information for it. Is there any one who can help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How are the individual files being accessed by the users? Directly from command line? Or from MapReduce jobs? Or both?

Comment: The individual files are accessed by the client program (users),later it will be simulation program according to the workload profile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the namenode logs - see *[Audit Logging](http://books.google.com/books?id=bKPEwR-Pt6EC&pg=PA280&lpg=PA280&dq=namenode%20logs%20FS%20Audit&source=bl&ots=kPcx7xedBo&sig=cjBjgoUR_KTJW9Fq4ow-BmkVnx0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n14tUYyLCYuu0AHZpoGoBw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=namenode%20logs%20FS%20Audit&f=false)* section of 'Hadoop, The Definitive Guide':

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked and followed this for Hadoop audit logging. But after this, I not see any different changes and I can not find this audit logs.